# select rows with a change in value

Tags: sas

I'd appreciate some guidance. I think I should use retain in a data step but I am not too sure how it works yet.

I have a table with 3 columns.

ID, Date, value (numerical).

The table is already sorted by ID1 and Date
I simply want to select the rows in which the amount changed based on the previous and drop the rows in which it does not. Example below

```
id      | Date  |amount |
A       |  01JAN|   1   |
A       |  02JAN|   1   | <- Drop this row
A       |  03JAN|   2   |  
B       |  01JAN|   0   |
B       |  02JAN|   1   |
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `NOTSORTED` keyword on the `BY` statement. So although the data is sorted by ID and DATE have the BY statement create the FIRST./LAST. flags based on ID and AMOUNT instead.

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  by id amount notsorted ;
  if first.amount;
run;
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you!
If I may elaborate on this, I am guessing that if two  rows have the same ID and Date, but different amounts, this code would keep both. If I wanted to keep only one of them (let's say the first) how would that change the code?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. If you want first value for a date then use ID DATE in the BY statement and use FIRST.DATE in the subsetting IF.  But not sure how that relates to your original request.  Perhaps you want to take the MIN() or MAX() amount per ID,DATE combination first to get to one observation per ID,DATE combination.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution uses the retain statement to remember the values from the previous record, compares it with the current record and deletes if the amount is the same (only checks for the same ID values - if you want to introduce some date conditions, you will need to do it here since your question does not specify any checks on the date).

```
data want;
  set have;
  by id;

  retain prev_id ' ';
  retain prev_amt;

  if _N_ = 1 then call missing(prev_id, prev_amt);
  if prev_id = id and prev_amt = amount then delete;

  prev_id = id;
  prev_amt = amount;

  keep id amount date;
run;
```